# strtotime() with only year return wrong data

Tags: php, strtotime

Following returning correct date

```
echo date('Y-m',strtotime('2009-3'));
```

But this returning wrong data when just year

```
echo date('Y',strtotime('2009'));
```

This showing current year. Whats wrong there

Comment: There is no correct date for `2009-3` nor for `2009`. They are not dates but date ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because only out of "2009" [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can't create a valid Unix timestamp. So you need to pass a full date like this:

```
echo date('Y',strtotime('2009-04-07'));
                       //^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also a quote from the manual shows this too:

> The **function expects** to be given a **string containing an English date format** and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp

**EDIT:**

If you only have the year you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php), like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y", "2009");
echo $date->format("Y");
```

output:

```
2009
```

Comment: I need unix timestamp with only year such as "2009", "2010" etc. Now what to do

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Pick a date.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam So did my edit worked for you or where are we with this question?

Comment: @Rizier123 In fact I need unix timestamp of years. How may i achieve this?? hope my requirements clear now

Comment: @RejoanulAlam `echo $date->getTimestamp();` Try this, I think this is what you want/need.